# Why does a pivot in every column implies a matrix has a left inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

"Show that if the equation $Ax=0$ has unique solution (i.e. if echelon form of $A$ has pivot in every column), then $A$ is left invertible."

$Ax=0$ has a trivial solution $x=0$. Now we are told that solution is also unique which means the columns of the matrix $A$ are linearly independent which implies there is a pivot in each column in echelon form. Now we just need to show that having a pivot in each column implies that matrix is left invertible. How can this be done?

Comment: If a column lacks a pivot then you can find some non-zero $x$ that satisfies this equation. This means the map $Ax$ is not injective, and so cannot be invertible.

Comment: You need to show two things: 1: $A$ is injective. 2: injective$\Leftrightarrow$left-invertible.